# не могу установить свойство css возможностями javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function setPlusIcon() {
  var allLIs = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
  for (var i = 0; i < allLIs.length; i++) {
    var li = allLIs[i];
    var allULs = li.getElementsByTagName("UL");
    if (allULs.length > 0) {
      if (allULs[0].className == "expandable")
        li.style.listStyleImage = "url('images/plus.gif')";
    }
  }
  var allA = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
  for (var i = 0; i < allA.length; i++) {
    allA[i].addEventListener('click', aClick);
  }
}
window.onload = setPlusIcon;

function aClick(e) {
  e = e || event;
  objA = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var li = objA.parentNode;
  console.log(li);
  var uls = li.getElementsByTagName("UL");
  if (uls.length == 0) return true;
  if (uls[0].style.display == "") {
    uls[0].style.display == "block"; //**ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НЕ УСТАНАВЛИВАЕТСЯ СВОЙСТВО block**
    li.style.listStyleImage = "url('images/minus.gif')";
  } else {
    uls[0].style.display == "";
    li.style.listStyleImage = "url('images/plus.gif')";
  }
}
```

```css
ul.expandable li {
  list-style-image: url('images/point.gif')
}
li ul.expandable {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Пример раскрывающегося списка</h1>
  <ul class="expandable">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Книги</a>
      <ul class="expandable">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Отечественные</a>
          <ul class="expandable">
            <li><a href="#">Детективы</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Научная фантастика</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Исторические</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Зарубежные</a>
          <ul class="expandable">
            <li><a href="#">Детективы</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Научная фантастика</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Исторические</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">DVD</a>
      <ul class="expandable">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Отечественные</a>
          <ul class="expandable">
            <li><a href="#">Детективы</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Научная фантастика</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Исторические</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Зарубежные</a>
          <ul class="expandable">
            <li><a href="#">Детективы</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Научная фантастика</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Исторические</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: uls[0].style.display == "block"; здесь идёт сравнение вместо присваивания, нужно uls[0].style.display = "block";

Comment: @ДмитрийКулевич Спасибо! Пойду отдыхать - перезанимался и не мог увидеть элементарную вещь. 5 раз проверил код. Еще раз спасибо!